# How to get rid of this exception " No bean named 'userDetailsService' is defined" although it is defined in xml file?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I am trying spring security authentication using database facing issues

DataController.java

```
package com.anzy.controller;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.anzy.dao.DataDao;
import com.anzy.domain.Employee;
@Controller
public class DataController {

 @Autowired
 DataDao dataDao;

 @RequestMapping("form")
 public ModelAndView getForm(@ModelAttribute Employee employee) {
  return new ModelAndView("form");
 }

 @RequestMapping("register")
 public ModelAndView registerUser(@ModelAttribute Employee employee) {
     dataDao.insertRow(employee);
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:list");
 }

 @RequestMapping("list")
 public ModelAndView getList() 
 {
  List employeeList = dataDao.getList();

  return new ModelAndView("list", "employeeList", employeeList);
 }

 @RequestMapping("delete")
 public ModelAndView deleteUser(@RequestParam int id) {
     dataDao.deleteRow(id);
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:list");
 }

 @RequestMapping("edit")
 public ModelAndView editUser(@RequestParam int id,
   @ModelAttribute Employee employee) {
  Employee employeeObject = dataDao.getRowById(id);
  return new ModelAndView("edit", "employeeObject", employeeObject);
 }

 @RequestMapping("update")
 public ModelAndView updateUser(@ModelAttribute Employee employee) {
     dataDao.updateRow(employee);
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:list");
 }

}
```

User.java

```
package com.anzy.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="UserAndRoles",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
    private List<Role> roles;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserStatus status;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public UserStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(UserStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

Role.java

```
package com.anzy.domain;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

public class Role
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="roleName")
    private String roleName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
    private List<User>users;

    public Role(int id, String roleName, List<User> users)
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.users = users;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }
    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }


}
```

UserStatus.java

```
package com.anzy.domain;

public enum UserStatus 
{
    ACTIVE,
    INACTIVE;

}
```

Employee.java

```
package com.anzy.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="employetest")
public class Employee {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private int id;

 @Column(name = "firstname")
 private String firstName;

 @Column(name = "lastname")
 private String lastName;

 @Column(name = "email")
 private String email;

 @Column(name = "phone")
 private String phone;

 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }

 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }

 public String getLastName() {
  return lastName;
 }

 public void setLastName(String lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }

 public String getEmail() {
  return email;
 }

 public void setEmail(String email) {
  this.email = email;
 }

 public String getPhone() {
  return phone;
 }

 public void setPhone(String phone) {
  this.phone = phone;
 }

}
```

UserDao.java

```
package com.anzy.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.anzy.domain.User;

public interface UserDao
{
    void addUser(User user);
    void editUser(User user);
    void deleteUser(int userId);
    User findUser(int useId);
    User findUserByName(String username);
    List<User> getAllUser();



}
```

UserDaoImpl.java

```
package com.anzy.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.anzy.domain.User;
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory session;

    public void addUser(User user)
    {
        session.getCurrentSession().save(user);

    }

    public void editUser(User user) {
        session.getCurrentSession().update(user);


    }

    public void deleteUser(int userId) {
        session.getCurrentSession().delete(findUser(userId));

    }

    public User findUser(int userId) {
        return (User) session.getCurrentSession().get(User.class,userId);
    }

    public User findUserByName(String username) {
Criteria criteria=session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
        return (User)criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User").list();
    }

}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
package com.anzy.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.anzy.dao.UserDao;
import com.anzy.domain.Role;
import com.anzy.domain.User;
import com.anzy.domain.UserStatus;
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl  implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        User user=userDao.findUserByName(username);
        if(user!=null)
        {
            String password=user.getPassword();
            boolean enabled=user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
            boolean accountNonExpired=user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
            boolean credentialsNonExpired=user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
            boolean accountNonLocked=user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
            Collection <GrantedAuthority> authorities=new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for(Role role:user.getRoles())
        {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
        }
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User secureUser=new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    return secureUser;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found !!!"); 

        }
    }

}
```

DataDao.java

```
package com.anzy.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.anzy.domain.Employee;

public interface DataDao 
{
 public int insertRow(Employee employee);

 public List<Employee> getList();

 public Employee getRowById(int id);

 public int updateRow(Employee employee);

 public int deleteRow(int id);

}
```

DataDaoImpl.java

```
package com.anzy.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.anzy.domain.Employee;

public class DataDaoImpl implements DataDao {

 @Autowired
 SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 @Transactional
 public int insertRow(Employee employee) {
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
  session.saveOrUpdate(employee);
  tx.commit();
  Serializable id = session.getIdentifier(employee);
  session.close();
  return (Integer) id;
 }

 public List getList() {
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List employeeList = session.createQuery("from Employee")
    .list();
  session.close();
  return employeeList;
 }

 public Employee getRowById(int id) {
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Employee employee = (Employee) session.load(Employee.class, id);
  System.out.println(employee);
  return employee;
 }

 public int updateRow(Employee employee) {
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
  session.saveOrUpdate(employee);
  tx.commit();
  Serializable id = session.getIdentifier(employee);
  session.close();
  return (Integer) id;
 }

 public int deleteRow(int id) {
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
  Employee employee = (Employee) session.load(Employee.class, id);
  session.delete(employee);
  tx.commit();
  Serializable ids = session.getIdentifier(employee);
  session.close();
  return (Integer) ids;
 }

}
```

spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.anzy" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="20" />
</bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">  
            <list>  
                <value>com.anzy.domain.Employee</value>  
            </list>  
        </property> 
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataDaoImpl" class="com.anzy.dao.DataDaoImpl" />

<!--    <bean id="dataServiceImpl" class="com.beingjavaguys.services.DataServiceImpl" />
 -->
</beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <form-login />
<!--         <logout invalidate-session="true" />
 -->    </http>

    <!-- <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="joseph" password="bagnes" authorities="Admin,User" />
                <user name="bernabe" password="jose" authorities="User" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager> -->

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="  org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
        <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
        </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
    <password-encoder hash="md5"></password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager> 

</beans:beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Comment: I edited the answer, it should work now (for a simplified version of your project). Generally speaking, and perhaps obviously, simplifying such problems as much as possible often makes their solution easier. I also think that your question got downvoted because you did not simplify your project enough, while preserving the error, and asking the question in the simplest setting possible.

Comment: @JohnDonn, It is better to teach how to do fishing or where to get fishes, instead feed them directly.

Comment: @John Dohn, Thanks folk.

Comment: @JohnDonn thanks friend for your help,I tried this way it works out now , and prior to that i went for alternate solution ie. pure spring java configurations that also works out for me :) .

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy I admire your words. Its just i am novice to spring framework and Trying get more hands on it.

Comment: @Sunilkumar, Thanks.Believe me, everyone is here to learn, enjoy the ride ;-)

Answer (score 0):

(edited from a previous version)

I created a simplified setting for your problem, and got the code to work.

Here are the two Java classes, first the service (in essense a stub, I did not try to simplify it further, the code has no particular significance):

```
package com.anzy.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl  implements UserDetailsService
{

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {

        Collection <GrantedAuthority> authorities=new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User secureUser=new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User("user", "user", true, true, true, true, authorities);
        return secureUser;
    }

}
```

and here is the controller (again, simplified to have just one method)

```
package com.anzy.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class DataController {

 @RequestMapping("form")
 public ModelAndView getForm() {
  return new ModelAndView("form");
 }

}
```

the four files under WEB-INF are:

spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.anzy">
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com.anzy.controller.*"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

spring-mvc.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.anzy.controller"/>

</beans>
```

spring-security.xml (note that I added  `use-expressions="true"` to the element `<http..`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean:beans xmlns:bean="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <form-login />
</http>


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </authentication-manager>

</bean:beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

The resulting web application starts with no exceptions.

**If, however, I change in web.xml**

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

to

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

and

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

to

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

then I get precisely the exception which was the subject of your question

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userDetailsService' is defined
```

Comment: I tried your way friend , and got even more complex errors including previous one as well :)